# Find records with a date field in the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, date

In my SQL query how do i make it find the records in the last 24 hours?
Eg

```
   SELECT * FROM news WHERE date < 24 hours
```

I usually do it by setting a variable to date() - 1 day and comparing it to that but I wondered whether the sql query way was faster?

Answer (score 165):

You simply select dates that are higher than the current time minus 1 day.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 83):

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this :  WHERE SomeDate > Now() -1   ?

Comment: @Andrew: I think it's `24 HOUR`, not `24 HOURS`.

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 22):

To get records from the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT * from [table_name] WHERE date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * from new WHERE date < DATE_ADD(now(),interval -1 day);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date > DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Never mind, I see you've added that it's MySQL you're using rather than SQL Server. Still, the answer might help someone else :)

Comment: To substract 1 day from current date has not the same result as to select a 24 hour intervall, which was the relevant question. The timeframe after substract 1 yay from GETDATE() has in maximum a timeframe of 47.99 hours

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to do this. The listed ones work great, but here's another way if you have a datetime field:

```
SELECT [fields] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE timediff(now(), my_datetime_field) < '24:00:00'
```

`timediff()` returns a time object, so don't make the mistake of comparing it to 86400 (number of seconds in a day), or your output will be all kinds of wrong.

Comment: You may wish to use < maketime(24,00,00). I noticed the behavior of the original query is inconsistent.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date < DATEADD(Day, -1, date)
```