# PHP & SQL - compare unix timestamp with MySQL CURDATE()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

i'm trying to do the following thing:
In my Database, I have rows with time in each one (using time() function).
For example: 1380300397.
Now, I'd like to build a query that gets the rows from the current day.
I've tried this query with no success:

```
SELECT `id`,DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM `facts` 
WHERE `app` = 1 AND DATE(`time`) = CURDATE()
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing unix timestapms in your database? MySQL has a DATETIME datatype specifically for storing dates and times.

Comment: For the next project I will do so. But in this project, I need to find a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079671/find-records-with-a-date-field-in-the-last-24-hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE`

Comment: Any description why to use `NOW()` ?

Comment: Why NOW()? I need only the date.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the best way to do it. I know it seems to be an overhead at the first glance, but this way you are not applying any function to your column, therefore your query can use index, if you have one on your `time` column.

```
SELECT 
    `id`, DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM
    `facts`
WHERE
    `app` = 1
        AND `time` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'))
        AND `time` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                    ' 00:00:00'))
```