# Compare a datetime field within 2 hours

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, compare

I have a table with the field `ENTERED_ON` (with both date and time value). I want to write a query that return records that have `ENTERED_ON` value that is past 2 hours comparing to current date time.

For example, if entered_on is `2014-05-06 11:00AM`, and currently it's `2014-05-06 2:00PM`, I would like to return all records that past the 2 hours when comparing to current date time.

Comment: Shows the work you did so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079671/find-records-with-a-date-field-in-the-last-24-hours duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can write query using INTERVAL. It will looks like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE `ENTERED_ON` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR)
```

Comment: DATE_ADD doesn't work. Oracle said invalid identifier.

Comment: @rvpals - that's because `date_add` is not an [Oracle date function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#sthref927). The first sentence of this answer is true, but the rest isn't useful for your situation.