# Conditional Statement to to print data count in the past hour from a particular Item if the count of the item for that past hour exceed 1000

Tags: sql-server

Conditional Statement to to print data count in the past hour from a particular Item if the count of the item for that past hour exceed 1000

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it, there isn't enough information to help. For example: Print where? In SSMS? Check how often? every hour? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to just add a WHERE-filter for an aggregate to your query that checks the count(*) value (a HAVING clause) and also checks some Datetime column for values between Start and End value.

You can use user-defined variables to set values, too.

Something perhaps like:

```
-- one hour ago
SET @start = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
-- right now
SET @end = NOW()

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE datetime >= @start AND datetime < @end
HAVING count(*) > 1000
GROUP BY *;
```

Then all you have to do is print our the result of the query.

Hope that helps!

**sources from other SO Posts**

[SO mysql-query-with-conditional-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608245/mysql-query-with-conditional-statement)
[SO MySQL within 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079671/find-records-with-a-date-field-in-the-last-24-hours#8079745)